# Hello World jQuery Code not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my system set-up to learn jquery and I can't even seem to get a simple hello world program to work and I'm not sure why.  It seems like it should work fine.

I'm using CI so here is my controller followed by my view.  Thanks.

`class Java extends Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('java_view');
    }

}`

The view file:

```
<script type = "javascript" src="http://localhost/ci/JS/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="javascript">   
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#hi").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });

   });
</script>
```

```
<a id = "hi" href="">Link</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried that URL to jQuery in your browser directly?  Also the type should be `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: What browser are you using? This works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @Nick Ya, link is good.

@Endangered Chrome, too.

I'm using XAMPP with CI as the php framework if that helps, although clearly the php is non-existant except for the view load.

Comment: Turned out to be a conflict with some stuff I had done with XAMPP - clean installed both that (well MAMP) and CI -> works well.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly, as proven in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tt5s7/

The error has to be in your Linkage to JQuery.js or in that Java Controller.

Comment: Giving you the answer since you turned me on to jsfiddle.  New here so I don't know if that's wrong or not, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

`text/javascript` is what the value should be for `type`, and did you `alert( $ == jQuery )` to make sure jQuery is loaded?